# Non-clickable items in a QTreeView?

Tags: qt4

I use a `QListWidget` with a `QStackedWidget` for user preference configuration, now

I would like to add a "`non-clickable`" item, not the editing triggers,

I mean like a indicator label (The `QLabel` plus a `QLine` widget underneath), but doesn't allow user to click on it.

i.e

```
---------------------------
| The Main Category Label |
---------------------------
| Clickable QStandardItem |
| Clickable QStandardItem |
| Clickable QStandardItem |
---------------------------
| The Secondary Category  |
---------------------------
| Clickable QStandardItem |
| Clickable QStandardItem |
| Clickable QStandardItem |
---------------------------
```

Is it possible?

I only see a `addItem` function, that doesn't seem to be for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using QListWidget then you should add QListWidgetItem with only `Qt::ItemIsEnabled` flag

```
QListWidget * wgt = new QListWidget;
QListWidgetItem * selectableItem = new QListWidgetItem("Selectable");
wgt->addItem(selectableItem);
QListWidgetItem * notSelectable = new QListWidgetItem("Not selectable");
notSelectable->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
wgt->addItem(notSelectable);
wgt->show();
```

To set widget on item:

```
QListWidget * wgt = new QListWidget;
QListWidgetItem * selectableItem = new QListWidgetItem("Selectable");
wgt->addItem(selectableItem);
wgt->setItemWidget(new QLineEdit());
QListWidgetItem * notSelectable = new QListWidgetItem("Not selectable");
notSelectable->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
wgt->addItem(notSelectable);
wgt->show();
```

Comment: That's good, but what about the "QLine" widget? Do I need to use Qt's delegate module or what?